# How to format Quill text as HTML outside of the editor?

Tags: quill

I have a form which posts the contents of the Quill editor to a PHP script. The PHP script then saves the text to a database. This same text can be loaded into the Quill editor at a later date. This all works fine and displays as expected.

FYI the code I am using is below:

```
<input name="editor1" type="hidden">
<div id="editor-container"></div>
<script src="https://cdn.quilljs.com/1.3.6/quill.js"></script>
<script>
    var quill = new Quill('#editor-container', {
                    modules: {
                        toolbar: [
                            ['bold', 'italic', 'underline'],
                            [{ list: 'ordered' }, { list: 'bullet' }]
                        ]
                    },
                    theme: 'snow'
                    });
    var form = document.querySelector('form');
    form.onsubmit = function() {
        var description = document.querySelector('input[name=editor1]');
        description.value = JSON.stringify(quill.getContents());
        return true;
    };

    <?php
    if (isset($description)) {
    ?>
    quill.setContents(<?=$description?>);
    <?php
    }
    ?>
</script>
```

The problem is this:

I don't want to have to load the Quill editor every time I want to display text which was generated using the Quill editor. I'd like to be able to display this text on a normal webpage, formatted using HTML.

For example, if someone typed the following into the Quill editor:

```
hello

 - this is in a list

***bye!***
```

I'd like to be able to take the output:

```
{"ops":[{"insert":"hello\nthis is in a list"},{"attributes":{"list":"bullet"},"insert":"\n"},{"attributes":{"italic":true,"bold":true},"insert":"bye!"},{"insert":"\n"}]}
```

And somehow convert it to the equivalent HTML, i.e.

```
hello
<ul>
    <li>this is in a list</li>
</ul>
<b><i>bye!</i></b>
```

Is there any way to do this out of the box?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

OK I figured this out.

It's possible to grab the HTML from the editor when it's on screen. I did this using `quill.root.innerHTML`.

So I need to save two things:

1. The Quill encoded text, used by the Quill editor only. I need this if I want to be able to load previously saved Quill text into the Quill editor.
2. The extracted HTML (via `quill.root.innerHTML`) which I can use to display the text on a webpage.

Comment: This helped me with the fact, that I can not use [(ngModel)] inside a <div>, which I have to use to get imageResize to work. Now I can work with the stuff I create inside the editor. Thank you!!!